# Ordenar dias en Chart Report rdl

Tags: sql, sql-server, reportviewer, rdlc

Mediante un store procedure obtengo los dias de la semana ordenados de L-V pero cuando paso los datos a las axis horizontales no me salen ordenados como en el query.

Resultado del query ordenado
[image: querydb]

Agrego los datos del query a la grafica

[image: horasxdia]

asi es como aparecen los dias revueltos, siendo que en el query estan ordenados

[image: daysorder]

Como le puedo hacer para que salgan ordenados como en el query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui la ordenacion de los dias:

Como en el resultado del query ya venia el numero correspondiente del dia(NumDay), en la asignacion de datos Category Group fui a Propiedades y seleccione el Tab Sorting.

En el combobox Sort by selecciones NumDay y en la opcion Order A to Z.

Esto me ordena los dias en la grafica por el numero de dia y no por el nombre del dia como lo tenia.

Saludos